# How to Remove redirection on magento site?

Tags: wordpress, magento, templates, redirect

There is a problem on my client site.Due to some of the **redirections set up for magento**.. I am not able to **access the wordpress pages.**. Whenever I try to access a wordpress page, I am redirected to a **magento 404 not found page**.... so please let me know how to remove redirection on my magento site??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous.  Is it the rewriting in .htaccess (or somewhere else) doing the redirect, or do they have redirects in the `core_url_rewrite` table that conflicts?

I would guess the former.  You need to create an alias or location for your Wordpress area that are distinctly different from your Magento area.  Often this is accomplished through a separate subdomain, like http://blog.example.com/ or through a suffix like http://www.example.com/blog/.